# compiling error with makefile:

Tags: c++, makefile

I am having the following error with makefile:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:7: recipe for target 'runme' failed
make: *** [runme] Error 1

That's my makefile code:

```
CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11
OBJ=main.o Shape.o
all: runme
runme: main.o Shape.o
    g++ $(OBJ) $(CXXFLAGS) -o runme
main.o: main.cpp Shape.hpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o
Shape.o: Shape.hpp Shape.cpp
    g++ $(CXXFLAGS) Shape.cpp -o Shape.o
clean: 
    rm -f *.o
distclean: clean
    rm -f runme
```

Comment: You sure you have a `main` function in one of those cpp files?

Comment: "undefined reference to ..." - that's a linker error you have there. Are you sure you linked the object defining the symbol that cannot be found?

Comment: You forgot to add "- c" to the flags when building `Shape.o` (and `main.o`, but that's a different problem).

Comment: Fixed. In the main function I put the following header: #ifndef SHAPES #define SHAPES which blocked the main function. Thanks!